# How to convert flux to flux density for a synthetic spectrum?

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, spectra, modeling, flux

I have several model SEDs generated by the CLOUDY spectral synthesis code. The data is formatted with one wavelength column and one flux column. I wish to perform Hubble synthetic photometry on these spectra using the Python synphot package. Unfortunately, the package requires the flux density units in my spectrum to be in erg/s/cm$^2$/AA, while my synthetic models have flux expressed in erg/s/cm$^2$.

I've tried to convert the flux to flux density by dividing each flux value by its corresponding wavelength, though I don't think this is right, as most sources say that flux density must be obtained by dividing flux over a wavelength/bin range. Theoretically, since I'm trying to calculate flux densities for individual wavelengths, wouldn't the flux density become infinite due to the width being 0?

In total, the question is: **How would I convert flux to flux density for tabular spectral data where flux is given for each wavelength?**